# join two tables in laravel with eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

hay can anyone help me please..

```
Table 1         Table 2
Id | province       Id | Id_table1 | country
5  | Example        1  |    5      | Eng
6  | Example        2  |    6      | Laz
```

and this is code in my controller

```
use App\Models\Table1;
public function gets(){
    $data = Table1::with('yoman')->get();

}
```

and this is code for join in my model Table1 and Table2

```
class Table1 extends model{
     public function yoman()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo(Table2::class,'id');
     }
}

class Table2 extends model{

}
```

after i joined why the value of table2 not show i just want to join `table1.Id = table2.Id_table1`?
sorry i'm newbie

Answer (score 0):

You could just use leftJoin

Model::leftJoin('model2', 'model2.column', '=', 'model.column')->get();

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `HasOne` relationship:

```
class Table1 extends model{
    public function yoman()
    {
         return $this->hasOne(Table2::class, 'Id_table1');
    }
}
```